# Cannot access class in java

Tags: java, class, include, cannot-find-symbol

I am trying to create a class to send information on the day of the week. For some reason when I try to include the class I get an error saying:

```
CreateCalendarVisuals.java:1: error: cannot access FindDateFindTime
import FindDateFindTime.FindDateFindTime;
                       ^
  bad class file: .\FindDateFindTime\FindDateFindTime.class
    class file contains wrong class: FindDateFindTime
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I have creat this code to find the date/time:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class FindDateFindTime
{
// public static void main(String[] args)
// {
//         LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
//         LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
//
//         System.out.println("Date: " + date + "; Time: " + time);
// }

public int dayOfWeek(int year, int month, int day)
{
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

        DayOfWeek d = date.getDayOfWeek();
        return d.getValue();
}
}
```

the class is public so I don't know why it would say that it cannot access. I am trying to call that class with this code:

```
import FindDateFindTime.FindDateFindTime;

public class CreateCalendarVisuals
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        FindDateFindTime d = new FindDateFindTime();
         System.out.println(d.dayOfWeek(2021, 04, 24));
}
}
```

My FindDateFindTime class is in a folder with the same name so I am that is why I have "import FindDateFindTime.FindDateFindTime". I have tried to look this up but I can't seem to find any solutions. I have also tried to do this with a package but it gives me the same issue. Could someone please help, I honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: Does FindDateFindTime use a package of the same name? If not, then the import should be the more simple: `import FindDateFindTime;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `CreateCalendarVisuals` imports the `FindDateFindTime` class as `FindDateFindTime.FindDateFindTime`; this means that your class `FindDateFindTime` belongs to the package `FindDateFindTime` so the first line of your class  `FindDateFindTime` has to be `package FindDateFindTime`. Note that according to the [package naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) your package's name should be rewritten as `finddatefindtime` in a *finddatefindtime* named directory, so your `FindDateFindTime` class declaration should be:

```
package finddatefindtime;

public class FindDateFindTime { ... }
```

And your `CreateCalendarVisuals` class:

```
import finddatefindtime.FindDateFindTime;

public class CreateCalendarVisuals { ... }
```

Comment: I have tried adding the package as you said and in the command prompt, I did "javac -d . FindDateFindTime.java" which made a folder appear with the .class file. Now I get an error saying `Error: Could not find or load main class FindDateFindTime
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: finddatefindtime/FindDateFindTime (wrong name: FindDateFindTime)`

And also in the CreatCalendarVisuals, i get this error, `CreateCalendarVisuals.java:1: error: package finddatefindtime does not exist import finddatefindtime.FindDateFindTime;`

Comment: @KlutzyMender, if you have a folder containing CreateCalendarVisuals.java and a subfolder in the same directory containing FindDateFindTime.java , you have to execute `javac  CreateCalendarVisuals.java` to compile both files.

Comment: Ok, i am very new to this so I am so confused, even if I execute the CreateCalendarVisuals I still get this error because I don't know how to create a package.

Comment: `CreateCalendarVisuals.java:1: error: package finddatefindtime does not exist
import finddatefindtime.FindDateFindTime;
                       ^
CreateCalendarVisuals.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        FindDateFindTime d = new FindDateFindTime();
        ^
  symbol:   class FindDateFindTime
  location: class CreateCalendarVisuals
CreateCalendarVisuals.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        FindDateFindTime d = new FindDateFindTime();
                                 ^
  symbol:   class FindDateFindTime
  location: class CreateCalendarVisuals
3 errors`

Comment: @KlutzyMender You have to create a directory containing CreateCalendarVisuals.java and a subdirectory called finddatefindtime containing FindDateFindTime.java.

Comment: Ok, I was just doing it wrong you are definitely right, thanks it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to import the class if  you are using the same package if you are using eclipse and netbeans.{output of the first program [no necessary to import the class if it is in the same package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAx5C.png)